# Safari is not showing the validation message on calling reportValidity

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, safari

I'm validating the form using a button click(not on form submit). The button is inside the form. Below is the code

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
 <Button id="validate-button" onclick="check()">Validate</Button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function check(e){
    document.getElementById('form').reportValidity();
}
```

While this works as expected in chrome where the form is validated and I can see a popover on the name input field with message: `Please fill in this field.`

However in safari this is not the case. I can see that the invalid input gets in focus but the validation popover message is missing in safari browser.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/cj6xynu1/

**Note: Please check above jsfiddle link on safari**

Comment: The problem is that **your** call to `reportValidity()` overrides the one from the browser. That could still be called a bug, but you don't need to call it yourself if you don't prevent the submission of the form. https://jsfiddle.net/e26jvgb8/

Comment: +1 agree, actually I already have a button of type submit in my form, I needed one more with type submit but its not allowed so I created a normal button with click handler, I'm stopping the propagation in the handler still the issue is occurred and is only solved by adding type attribute with value button

Comment: @Kaiido Added jsfiddle in the question. Please check

Comment: in the fiddle you are not stopping the propagation of the event, and what would need to be stopped is the default behavior anyway, through preventDefault() https://jsfiddle.net/ef1gw2L0/

Answer (score 0):

It turn out that the issue is because of the missing `type` attribute on the button. After adding `type="button"` the validation message started showing up in safari.

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cj6xynu1/1/

**Note: Check the above link in safari**

Comment: It's not only Safari, it's [by specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type). "*The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state.*"

Comment: Yes right, in case of capturing the click event and stopping it from propagation, chrome is correctly showing the validation popover, it doesn't care if button is of what type. But safari cares and do not show it